# "Page isn't redirecting properly" when I set gerrit.canonicalWebUrl

Tags: gerrit

After installing Gerrit following `Using Gerrit in production` section from https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/docker-gerrit, the field was set automatically to this value:

```
[gerrit]
        canonicalWebUrl = http://eac32ee72f2b/
```

I want to use Gerrit behind a reverse proxy, so I configured Apache2 like this:

```
ProxyPass / http://192.168.19.241:8080/ nocanon
```

This works, but as soon as I set `gerrit.canonicalWebUrl` to `https://gerrit.example.com`, I get *The page isn’t redirecting properly* and the URL in the browser becomes `https://gerrit.example.com//login/`.

If I try to set the cannonical web url to `https://gerrit.example.com/g/` and update Apache2 accordingly to:

```
ProxyPass /g/ http://192.168.19.241:8080/g/ nocanon
```

I get "Not found" message in the browser and the URL in the bar now reads `https://gerrit.example.com/g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g//g`. If I inspect the HTTP headers, for the initial request for page `https://gerrit.example.com/g` I get a 301 redirect to `https://gerrit.example.com/g//g`.

In all cases, the configuration `httpd.listenUrl` was `proxy-http://*:8080`.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I would like to set the proper web URL, because it is visible in the links to checkout repositories over HTTP, and maybe also in other places.

Comment: Have you checked the DNS for gerrit.company.com? I assume company.com is a placeholder for your actual company.

Comment: Please use `example.com` when needing dummy names for illustration purposes, not something else madeup.

Comment: Are Gerrit and Apache2 on the same server or not?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I fixed the example.com problem. Currently gerrit is not on the same server as Apache2. In the end I plan to run them on the same server.

Comment: @barrycarter the Gerrit subdomain is not yet registered to point to this server, so for now I hacked c:\windows\system32\etc\hosts. So neither Apache2 nor gerrit will get this if they query DNS. But I have been using like this virtual hosts and all was well. And I think that Gerrit, being behind a firewall, should not query DNS...

Comment: @andi OK, that's what I meant. Since it's a private IP address, I wasn't suggest global DNS-- just something (like /etc/hosts) that makes your browser take you to the correct IP address. Unless I'm missing something, things are working for you when you use the IP address, but not when you use the domain name?

Comment: @barrycarter: thanks for the help. After I posted the question I got myself a real domain, and problem persisted. But fixing the listenUrl to `proxy-https` did the trick. It was my fault for not reading properly the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed this chapter: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-reverseproxy.html#_ssl

It is written to use `proxy-https` instead of `proxy-http` when using HTTPS with Apache2. It all worked with this configuration:

```
[httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-https://*:8080/
```